# The Heechee Saga / Gateway - Does it occur in a parallel universe?

Tags: parallel-universe, heechee-saga

In *Gateway*, by Frederick Pohl, there is a line that has bothered me every time I've read the series.  Except for it, there is nothing that I am aware of in the books to indicate that the events occur in anything other than a near future version of our own universe.  My question is, does this single comment stand on its own, or have I missed some other clues elsewhere in the series?  Did Frederick Pohl ever comment on whether the Heechee Saga occurs in our universe or not?

In the book there are passages stuck throughout the text: classified ads for the Gateway space station, mission reports, the programming language of one of the characters, and a series of scientific lectures by a great mind of the series, Professor Hegramet.  One of them, near the end of chapter 22, is titled *A Note on Metallurgy*, and it contains the following passage regarding the mysterious, blue, glowing "Heechee metal":

> Professor Hegramet: The Bureau says there are some posturanic elements in it, and probably they drive the radiation; but we don’t know what they are. There’s also something in it that looks like an isotope of copper. **Well, copper doesn’t have any stable isotopes. Up to now.**

Of course, in our reality, copper has two stable isotopes, <sup>63</sup>Cu and <sup>65</sup>Cu.

The only other indication that Gateway might not be in our universe is the presence of alien tunnels on Venus.  The book was written with Venus accurately portrayed as a boiling pit, and only the tunnels are supposed to be livable.  It seems entirely possible that such a thing could currently exist beneath its surface without us having discovered it yet.

Using the stability of various isotopes to indicate the difference in strong force interactions among universes is not a new idea.  Asimov famously did the same thing in *The Gods Themselves* with tungsten and plutonium.  However, in that book the difference in strong force interaction strength was the driver of the entire story.  It doesn't seem likely that Pohl, another hard scifi master, would have thrown this into the book as an aside without considering the enormous physical and technological consequences of it for the universe.

My thoughts on the possibilities:

1. This was intentional but undeveloped.  It was an unusual instance of sloppy storytelling in a scifi classic.
2. This was a mistake.  He meant to write about technetium or promethium and wrote copper instead.  There is a typo in the same passage, the version I have (and the only one that I can find online) clearly wasn't proofread well.
3. There is additional information I've missed or am not aware of.  I really hope it's this, honestly.  Except for plot driven requirements (ex: superluminal travel) the series has relatively solid science.

Does anyone have additional information to indicate whether one of these, or perhaps something else entirely, is correct?

Comment: I've read almost the entire series and I believe that it does not take place in a parallel universe.  Though alternate universes are discussed in the series.

Comment: [Science Marches On](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main.ScienceMarcheson) (caution: TVTropes link.)

Comment: @JoeL. This is information that has been known since the 1930's.  It's not a case of the author simply making it up or having correct information.  The idea of isotopes is such that knowing about them and radioactivity at all would preclude a statement of this type.

Answer (score 4):

I would guess that Pohl is probably using the word "isotope" in a slightly nonstandard way — to mean "uncommon isotope." That is, protium would just be "hydrogen", but deuterium would be "an isotope of hydrogen." Both stable isotopes of copper are relatively common in naturally-occurring copper, so they would just count as "copper" and not as "an isotope of copper." On the other hand, deuterium, helium-3, and carbon-13 would count as "stable isotopes" of hydrogen, helium, and carbon, by virtue of being uncommon enough to be remarked upon.

Comment: I suppose that this is possible, but it seems unlikely.  The sentence really doesn't make sense in that regard without isotope meaning *isotope*.  If he had wanted to say that it contained a new, stable isotope of copper, then that would have been simple enough to write, but just saying that copper doesn't have *any* stable isotopes, that's a pretty clearcut sentence.

Comment: I think this would be more reasonable if copper had only one common isotope, but it's the best I can do. At least it moves Pohl's error — if it is an error — from "doesn't understand radioactivity" to "forgot to double-check a periodic table that one time", which seems a lot more excusable.